# SQL server unit test on TFS build

Tags: unit-testing, tfs

We has a solution which is being built by TFS and SQL server unit tests which should be run on each build. The tests part also consists of a Database project which should be deployed to localDB before tests are running. 
The config for SQL server unit test project is:

```html
<configSections>
        <section name="SqlUnitTesting" type="Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting.Configuration.SqlUnitTestingSection, Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SnapDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=SampleDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
    <SqlUnitTesting>
        <DatabaseDeployment DatabaseProjectFileName="..\..\..\..\Database\SampleDatabase.sqlproj" Configuration="Debug" />
        <DataGeneration ClearDatabase="true" />
        <ExecutionContext Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ConnectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=SampleDatabase;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" CommandTimeout="30" />
        <PrivilegedContext Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ConnectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=SampleDatabase;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" CommandTimeout="30" />
    </SqlUnitTesting>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Everything work fine on my local machine but on TFS it fails with an error:

> An error occurred while SQL Server unit testing settings were being read from the configuration file.  Click the test project, open the SQL Server Test Configuration dialog box from the SQL menu, add the settings to the dialog box, and rebuild the project.

The guys assumes that the tests worked fine on TFS 2013 but after the upgrading to TFS 2015 we started to get this error. Tried different solutions found here and over the internet but nothing helps. What am I missing?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another SQL Server instance (not localdb, using another SQL Server instance works fine for me).

On the other hand, you are using windows authentication, so make sure the build service account has the enough permission (e.g. create database) for target SQL Server.

Comment: I've tried to use another instance of SQL Server (SQL Server 2014 and SQL Express) with no luck. Also tried to play with permissions of service account and also pass different credentials instead of using windows authentication with the same result

Comment: @Andrew Could you connect to that SQL Server from another machine? Does different credential means SQL account (SQL authentication)? Try to change service account to your account and check the result.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Both TFS and SQL server are set up on my local machine, so yes I could connect to the SQL server. "Try to change service account to your account" probably did not get your idea.

Comment: @Andrew If you are using VNext build and running as service, open Services > Find build agent service> Double click > Select Log on >Change account.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the TFS setup but if this service is VSO agent unfortunately I could not change the services log on due to the our company security policies.

Comment: @Andrew Does "different credential" means SQL account (SQL authentication)? Could you connect to the SQL Server with this SQL account and can create database? On the other hand, do you use VNext build or XAML build?

Comment: Yes this is the user created on SQL server with dbcreator and sysadmin rights. We are using VNext build but unfortunately I'm not sure of name of the service name.

Comment: Do you select SQL Server Authentication when create a new user in SQL Server? Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? If so, you can share it on the OneDrive.

Comment: Here is the link to a zipped solution https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aq_Mm7VqiJX_bIy_bobEc6456Xc it is a simple dummy project based on the settings of our application and with the same problem. One think I left as is that .runsettings file is empty since I'm not sure what it should contain to support database deployment. Thank you